# Casting DerivedA<DerivedB> to BaseA<BaseB>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I am writing an event system and have hit a stumbling block when trying to store events of different generic types.

Events are defined like so:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<EventInfo>(object sender, EventInfo eventInfo) where EventInfo : IEventInfo;

public interface IEventInfo { }

public interface IEvent<EventInfo> where EventInfo : IEventInfo
{
    void Publish(object sender, EventInfo e);
    void Subscribe(EventHandler<EventInfo> evtHandler);
    void Unsubscribe(EventHandler<EventInfo> evtHandler);
}

public class Event<EventInfo> : IEvent<EventInfo> where EventInfo : IEventInfo
{
    private event EventHandler<EventInfo> eventHandler;

    public void Publish(object sender, EventInfo e)
    {
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(sender, e);
    }

    public void Subscribe(EventHandler<EventInfo> evtHandler)
    {
        this.eventHandler -= evtHandler;
        this.eventHandler += evtHandler;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(EventHandler<EventInfo> evtHandler)
    {
        this.eventHandler -= evtHandler;
    }
}
```

This model seems to work for subscribing and publishing, but the main reason I have implemented my own event class is so that I can use it with an event aggregator, allowing me to decouple my components:

```
public class EventAggregator
{
    private IDictionary<Type, IEvent<IEventInfo>> dictionary;

    public EventAggregator()
    {
        this.dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IEvent<IEventInfo>>();
    }

    public EventType GetEvent<EventType>() where EventType : class, IEvent<IEventInfo>, new()
    {
        IEvent<IEventInfo> evt;
        Type evtType = typeof(EventType);
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(evtType, out evt))
            dictionary[evtType] = evt = new EventType();
        return evt as EventType;
    }
}
```

The above function does not work with derived `EventInfo` classes. For example:

```
public class FooEventInfo : IEventInfo { }
public class FooEvent : Event<FooEventInfo> { }

EventAggregator ea = new EventAggregator();
var x = ea.GetEvent<FooEvent>(); // Error 3: The type 'TestEvent' cannot be used as type parameter 'EventType' in the generic type or method 'EventAggregator.GetEvent<EventType>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TestEvent' to 'IEvent<IEventInfo>'.
```

Why does this cast fail, given that `TestEvent : Event<TestEventInfo>`, `Event<TestEventInfo> : IEvent<TestEventInfo>` and `TestEventInfo : IEventInfo`?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129606/cannot-implicitly-convert-mytypefoo-to-mytypeifoo/12129658#12129658)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Event<FooEventInfo>` is not compatible with `IEvent<IEventInfo`.

If you have a type `T'` derived from `T`, it does not mean that `A<T'>` is derived from or in any way compatible to `A<T>`!

Take this example

```
class Animal { ... }
class Dog : Animal { ... }
class Cat : Animal { ... }

List<Animal> animals = new List<Dog>(); // Seems to be possible
animals.Add(new Dog());
animals.Add(new Cat()); // Crashhhh!
```

Adding a `Cat` to `animals` should be possible, but because the list is in reality a list of dogs, you would be adding a `Cat` into a `Dog`-list! Therefore the two types cannot be compatible!

Comment: Thanks, I guess this makes sense when you put it in this context. How could I restructure the code to keep a list of generalised events?

Comment: If you are working with .NET Framework 4.0, there is some relief to this situation with the `in` and `out` keywords. They can be applied to generic type parameters of interfaces. If a generic type parameter appears only as input parameter or only as output parameter inside the whole interface, youy can apply this keywords to it. Possibly you will have to restructure or even split your interface into to interfaces in order to be able to apply these keywords. They allow contravariance and covariance and make the generic type parameters compatible with more or less derived types.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're running into the fact that C# doesn't support covariance.  Take a look at [this](http://buiba.blogspot.com/2009/06/so-i-get-onto-phone-for-my-first-job.html) post to read about covariance/contravariance in C#, and an (ugly) workaround that he's come up with.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) is a deeper explanation of the concepts at question.