# Cannot implicitly convert type 'app.a1<<string>>' to 'app.a1<<object>>'

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, covariance

i am trying to understand the generics and co-variance from the following code when i try to compile. i am getting error like

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'ConsoleApplication1.a1<<string>>'` to
>   `'ConsoleApplication1.a1<<object>>'`

```
class a1<T>
{
    public   void Fmethod( T a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().ToString());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        a1<string> aa1 = new a1<string>();
        a1<object> aa2 = new a1<object>();
        object b;
        aa2.Fmethod(b);

        aa1.Fmethod("aa");
        aa2 = aa1;
         Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: The first word between bracket is string and second is object.

Comment: Classes by themselves in C# are neither covariant nor contravariant, they're **invariant**. You can implement an interface that can be covariant or contravariant but then the access to the object has to go through an interface reference.

Comment: [Potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129606/cannot-implicitly-convert-mytypefoo-to-mytypeifoo) except it's contra- not covariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx):

> Generic classes are invariant. In other words, if an input parameter specifies a `List<BaseClass>`, you will get a compile-time error if you try to provide a `List<DerivedClass>`.

Applying to your example, since you are assigning an object of type `a1<string>` to a variable of type `a1<object>`, there is an error.